# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.chains.question_answering' using Render and github

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I use github and Render to deploy my code.
but it can't work in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.chains.question_answering'`.

```
# my requirements.txt
python==3.11
line-bot-sdk
flask
openai==0.28.1
gunicorn
PyPDF2
pymupdf
faiss
faiss-cpu
langchain
requests
```

I have appoint my python to 3.11 but it either not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.  Please also include details on how you're running this.  Are you using the same python binary environment associated to the installed modules?